# How to fix 30.0.2 is missing

Tags: kotlin

I want to build an app and when I just make or run an app there is an error saying that 30.0.2 is missing and when it says to download it from SDK manager then whenever I go to SDK manager and download that 30.0.2 it is said that it's and successful and check the sum ID locks and I download anything else at other than 30.0.2 it down loaded successfully please help me if someone can
And if someone is really kind to help I can give him a virtual access to my PC and he can fix it by his PC and but I had sector your help will really help me because I want to start building an application and this is the first error that I am not able to call and if you help if it it means a lot Tumi you can WhatsApp me at 997 1040 966 thank you

Comment: try to use 30.0.3 instead of 30.0.2 and if possible share you app's **build.gradle** for better understanding and please don't share you personal info like contact number here.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error message(s) you get plus information on your OS, compiler, environment and everything that might be relevant to the problem.